# PHP add array inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem to add array into array. I cannot resolve it.

I have this array $A:

```
Array
(
    [1001] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 'Joe'
                        [surname] => 'Doe'
                        [age]  => 20
                        [height] => 180
                        [weight] => 80
                     )
            )
)
```

And I have this array $B:

```
Array
(
    [height] => 200
    [weight] => 100
)
```

How to create new array to get this result:

```
Array
(
    [1001] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 'Joe'
                        [surname] => 'Doe'
                        [height] => 180
                        [weight] => 80
                        [age]  => 20
                     )
            )
    [1001] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 'Joe2'
                        [surname] => 'Doe2'
                        [height] => 200
                        [weight] => 100
                        [age]  => 22
                     )
            )
)
```

I use this, but the result is not correct:

```
$array[1001][] = [
            'name'   => 'Joe2',
            'surname'=> 'Doe2',
            $B,
            'age' => 22
        ];
```

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the operator `+` to merge your arrays:

```
$array = array(
    1001 => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Joe',
            'surname' => 'Doe',
            'height' => 180,
            'weight' => 80,
            'age'  => 20
        )
    ),
);

$B = array('height' => 200, 'weight' => 100);

$array[1001][] = [
            'name'   => 'Joe2',
            'surname'=> 'Doe2',
            'age' => 22
        ] + $B;

print_r($array);
```

Will outputs:

```
Array
(
    [1001] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Joe
                    [surname] => Doe
                    [height] => 180
                    [weight] => 80
                    [age] => 20
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Joe2
                    [surname] => Doe2
                    [age] => 22
                    [height] => 200
                    [weight] => 100
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `] + $B;` ... I didn't even know you could do that with arrays :D

Comment: How simple. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Syscall ... knew about comparison, just it never even occurred to me to consider joining 2 arrays with `+` before.

Answer (score 3):

Try array_merge():

```
$array[1001][] = array_merge(['name'=>'Joe2','surname'=> 'Doe2','age' => 22],$B);
```

OR

```
$array[1001][] = ['name'=>'Joe2','surname'=> 'Doe2','age' => 22] + $B;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_merge` like this:

```
$array[1001][] = array_merge([
    'name'   => 'Joe2',
    'surname'=> 'Doe2',
    'age' => 22
], $B);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$innerArray = array();
$item1Array = array();
array_push($item1Array,"Data 1");
array_push($item1Array,"Data 2");
$item2Array = array();
array_push($item2Array,"Data 3");
array_push($item2Array,"Data 4");
array_push($innerArray, $item1Array);
array_push($innerArray, $item2Array);
$result = array();
$result["result"] = "Success";
$result["user"] = $innerArray;
```

Result :

```
{
    "result" => "Success",
    "user" => [
        [0] =>[
            [0]=>"Data 1",
            [1]=>"Data 1",
        ],
        [1] =>[
            [0]=>"Data 3",
            [1]=>"Data 4",
        ]
    ]
}
```

Hope it helps.